# Remix uploading the wrong contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-debugging

I have a contract called `bridgeStacked` that uses a library called `BytesLib`.
When I have both loaded into Remix, I compile and deploy `bridgeStacked` from in Remix.
First, I notice that in the log it says

`creation of library browser/bridgeStacked.sol:BytesLib pending...`

So I don't kno why it includes BytesLib in that.
Then nothing shows up under the `deployed` tab - I have to manually get the tx hash from the log and look at a Ropsten block explorer to get the address of the contract that was created, then load that into the `At Address` field which correctly loads the right functions in the Deployed Contracts section.
Then why I try and call a simple test function:

```
function test(uint256 _val) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _val;
    }
```

It returns `0` when I enter `2`. If I remove `view` and make it a write tx, the tx just fails even though it's mined. Similarly fails when called from web3.py.

What's going on here? I *think* the issue is that the wrong contract is being deployed, but why? :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a Remix bug, you can compare the compiled and deploeyd byte code of a smart contract to make sure that the contracts are different.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. You were right - I loaded the exact same code into Truffle and it worked fine